# Inkscape - break objects apart and reassembling them

Tags: inkscape, shapes

I need a combination of two shapes; i) a hexagonal shape and ii) a country outline. The final product shall look like the image attached.

I have managed to cut and clip the two forms so far that I have the final output. Nevertheless, in order to work with the result, I need to colour the hexagons differently. And there lies the problem; when wanting to select individual hexagons, the layer from which I clipped the shape still occurs and spreads across the border of what I have cut.

Hence, I need a guideline on how to 'combine' these to shapes (sort of intersecting the paths, which does not work).

[image: Final Output]

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SE. Can you please specify what you mean by *when wanting to select individual hexagons, the layer from which I clipped the shape still occurs and spreads across the border of what I have cut?* I have no problem in producing what I expect to be your desired result in the way you describe it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

1. create the structure you wish to have inside the reference polygon (in this case, the country shape);
2. combine them all, using *path → union;*
3. *intersect* the structure and the reference polygon;
4. *break apart* the new, structured polygon.

Comment: A little question: do you need to approximate the bound of the country with the hexagons or just to fill it? Have you tried to use an hexagon based [pattern](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Attributes-Fill-Stroke.html) instead?